# replace/change duplicate columns values where column name is same but values are different, then drop duplicate columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

Is there any way to drop duplicate columns, but replacing their values depending upon conditions like
in table below, I would like to remove duplicate/second A and B columns, but want to replace the value of primary A and B (1st and 2nd column) where value is 0 but 1 in duplicate columns.
Ex - In 3rd row, where A, B have value 0 , should replace with 1 with their respective duplicate columns value..

Input Data :

[image]

Output Data:

[image]

This is an example of a problem I'm working on, my real data have around 200 columns so i'm hoping to find an optimal solution without hardcoding columns names for removal..

Comment: Please add the input data and the expected output (not in images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) per duplicated columns names if only `1,0` values in columns:

```
df = df.any(axis=1, level=0).astype(int)
```

Or if need maximal value per duplicated columns names:

```
df = df.max(axis=1, level=0)
```

Comment: @ShaktiSingh - sorry, my typo.